# SQL display status for records with null values

Tags: sql, ms-access, null

I am trying to create a query that lists records from table 1 along with a status based on  corresponding records in table 2 that have null values in one or more of the fields.  The problem I am running into is how to include records from table 1 which have no corresponding record in table 2.

In my example, I want to list the names of all students in ***tblStudent*** along with a field indicating the status of their schedule in ***tblStudentSchedule***.  If either ***course*** or ***teacher*** field in ***tblStudentSchedule*** is Null or no corresponding record in ***tblStudentSchedule*** is found then I want to display **"Incomplete"**.  Otherwise, I want to display **"Complete"**.

**desired result**

```
Name  | Schedule Status
-----------------------
Bob   | Incomplete     
Sally | Incomplete
Jane  | Incomplete
Matt  | Incomplete
Jim   | Complete
```

I'm working in **Access**.  I would post my query attempts but I think they would just confuse the issue.  This is probably very basic but I am having a mental block trying to wrap my brain around this one.

**tblStudent**

```
studentID | studentName
-----------------------
1         | Bob
2         | Sally
3         | Jane
4         | Matt
5         | Jim
```

**tblStudentSchedule**

```
studentID | period | course | teacher
-------------------------------------
1         | 1      | math   | Jones
1         | 2      | <null> | Watson
2         | 1      | reading| <null>
4         | 1      | <null> | Crick
5         | 1      | math   | Jones
```

Comment: I suggest reading about the different types of joins, particularly outer joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  s.studentName as Name
,       iif(sum(iif(ss.course is null or ss.teacher is null, 1, 0)) = 0,
            'Complete', 'Incomplete')
        as [Schedule Status]
from    tblStudent s
left join    
        tblStudentSchedule ss
on      ss.studentID = s.studentID
group by
        s.studentName
```

A `left join` returns a single row with `null` when a match is not found.  So the check on `ss.course is null` will also trigger when the student is absent from the schedule table.

Comment: Can you document that claim?  I think they work just fine, f.e. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php

Comment: @Andomar a `CASE` can only be used in VBA code, you need to use `IIf` in a SQL query.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all the quick responses.  This is close and you clued me into a way to use iif that I hadn't considered but the result is not exactly what I am looking for.  Please see the "desired results" in my original post to see what I am referring to.

Each student should only be listed once.  "Bob" is listed twice because there are two records which make up his schedule.  The studentID and period make up the primary key.  A schedule may have a variable number of records for each student.  Maybe my schedule table design is all wrong?

Comment: You could group by name, and per group, say that the sum of incomplete rows has to be zero.  Updated in answer.

Comment: Again.. Wow. Thanks!  That works! I WAS looking at this wrong. It would have taken me quite a while to arrive at this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If no corresponding record in tblStudentSchedule is found, you can get rows from this table as null coulmns by using left or right joins. Read below:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/left-join-right-join-operations-HP001032251.aspx

And then to convert null column use isnull function
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/isnull.php

Or use a case statement to check for null
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php